# Unit Testing Android Studio Textview

Tags: android, unit-testing

This is my main activity which gets a json array from a URL. My problem is that when I try and Unit test what should be in the textview it gives me a null pointer exeption.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
TextView txtJson;
ProgressDialog pd;
public static TextView testString;
String jsonString = null;
List<Location> locations;`enter code here`


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtJson = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvJsonItem);
    testString = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test_for_string);

    new JsonTask().execute("https://wsu-dining-service.s3.amazonaws.com/current-menu.json");
}

protected void postCreate()
{
    mapStrinToClass();
    testString.setText(locations.get(0).getName());
}


private void mapStrinToClass()
{
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = objectMapper.getFactory();
    try {
        JsonParser jsonParser = jsonFactory.createParser(jsonString);
        locations = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString,
                new TypeReference<List<Location>>() {
                });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


private class JsonTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pd.setMessage("Please wait");
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();


            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line+"\n");
                Log.d("Response: ", "> " + line);   //here u ll get whole response...... :-)

            }

            return buffer.toString();


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (pd.isShowing()){
            pd.dismiss();
        }
        jsonString = result;
        postCreate();
    }
}
```

}

My unit test
* When I run the app the textview is populated with "Tim & Jeanne's Dining Commons" but the test fails and says the testString.getText().toString(); is null

```
@Test
public void isMenuCorrect() {
    String menuTxt = MainActivity.testString.getText().toString();
    assert(menuTxt == "Tim & Jeanne's Dining Commons");

}
```

Comment: When you run your app, the Android framework executes your activity's `onCreate()` code (as well as other things). When you run the test, none of that happens. So `MainActivity.testString` is null. See https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing for information on automated UI testing.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use Espresso to run UI tests, under the androidTest folder. Example:

```
onView(allOf(withId(R.id.tvJsonItem), withText("Tim & Jeanne's Dining Commons")).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

Basically what we're doing here is checking if a view with id `R.id.tvJsonItem` and with a text "Tim & Jeanne's Dining Commons" is displayed on the screen. Now how to run Espresso tests is not in this question's scope.

Second, your production code should never know what's going on in the tests, like you have created a TextView just to be used in your unit tests.

Finally, never have static references to your views since you can't guarantee your activity has been created by the time you try to access them. In fact, a view should only be seen by its parent. In your case, the reference TextView should be private in your activity.

Comment: Thank you, espresso makes it so much easier